# Как сделать так чтобы при нажатии на кнопку выполнялось "скрыть/показать" но только чтобы закрывался контент на родителя кнопки на которую нажал?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Когда я нажимаю на a.jobs_more закрываются все .jobs_descript_full, а нужно чтобы только в том блоке в котором я нажал на кнопку.

Мне нужно чтобы когда я нажимал на кнопку a.jobs_more выполнялось "скрыть/показать" элемента .jobs_descript_full только в родительском для себя (a.jobs_more) блоке .job_item

```js
let moreValid;

function moreJobs() {
  $('.jobs_descript_full').hide();
  moreValid = false;

  $('.jobs_more').on('click', function() {
    $('.jobs_descript_full').toggle();
  });
}

moreJobs()
```

```html
<div class="job_item">

  <p class="jobs_title">Корректировка проекта полигона твердых отходов ПАО «Распадская»</p>
  <p class="jobs_descript">Сбор и анализ исходных данных, обоснование технических и технологических решений по объекту «Корректировка проекта полигона твердых отходов ПАО «Распадская».</p>
  <p class="jobs_descript_full">В рамках реализации специальных технических условий (СТУ) на проектирование объекта АО «Учалинский ГОК». Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник. Ствол шахты «Скипо-Клетевая» в составе проектной документации АО «Учалинский ГОК». Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник.
    Отработка запасов месторождения на полное развитие - 4,5 млн. т/год выполнен Отчет от 22 июля 2021 г. о НИР «Расчет крепи и корректировка параметров армирования крепи по объекту АО «Учалинский ГОК». Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник. Ствол шахты «Скипо-Клетевая»
    в составе проектной документации ОАО «Учалинский ГОК» Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник. Отработка запасов месторождения на полное развитие - 4,5 млн. т/год». В ходе расчета осуществлена проверка несущей способности крепи и оптимизация параметров армирования
    на участках пород, отнесенных к IV категории устойчивости.
  </p>
  <a class="jobs_more">Подробнее <span><ion-icon name="chevron-down-outline"></ion-icon></span></a>

</div>

<div class="job_item">

  <p class="jobs_title">Расчет крепи ствола шахты «Скипо-Клетевая» рудника месторождения «Юбилейное»</p>
  <p class="jobs_descript">Научно-исследовательская работа (НИР) от 28 июля 2021 г. «Расчет крепи ствола шахты «Скипо-Клетевой» ООО «Башкирская медь» месторождение «Юбилейное» и сопряжений ствола с горизонтами».</p>
  <p class="jobs_descript_full">В рамках реализации специальных технических условий (СТУ) на проектирование объекта АО «Учалинский ГОК». Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник. Ствол шахты «Скипо-Клетевая» в составе проектной документации АО «Учалинский ГОК». Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник.
    Отработка запасов месторождения на полное развитие - 4,5 млн. т/год выполнен Отчет от 22 июля 2021 г. о НИР «Расчет крепи и корректировка параметров армирования крепи по объекту АО «Учалинский ГОК». Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник. Ствол шахты «Скипо-Клетевая»
    в составе проектной документации ОАО «Учалинский ГОК» Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник. Отработка запасов месторождения на полное развитие - 4,5 млн. т/год». В ходе расчета осуществлена проверка несущей способности крепи и оптимизация параметров армирования
    на участках пород, отнесенных к IV категории устойчивости.
  </p>
  <a class="jobs_more">Подробнее <span><ion-icon name="chevron-down-outline"></ion-icon></span></a>

</div>

<div class="job_item">

  <p class="jobs_title">Расчет крепи ствола шахты «Скипо-Клетевая» Ново-Учалинского подземного рудника</p>
  <p class="jobs_descript">Научно-исследовательская работа (НИР) от 22 июля 2021 г. «Расчет крепи и корректировка параметров армирования крепи по объекту «АО «Учалинский ГОК». Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник. Ствол шахты «Скипо-Клетевая» в составе проектной документации «ОАО
    «Учалинский ГОК» Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник. Отработка запасов месторождения на полное развитие - 4,5 млн. т/год».</p>
  <p class="jobs_descript_full">В рамках реализации специальных технических условий (СТУ) на проектирование объекта АО «Учалинский ГОК». Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник. Ствол шахты «Скипо-Клетевая» в составе проектной документации АО «Учалинский ГОК». Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник.
    Отработка запасов месторождения на полное развитие - 4,5 млн. т/год выполнен Отчет от 22 июля 2021 г. о НИР «Расчет крепи и корректировка параметров армирования крепи по объекту АО «Учалинский ГОК». Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник. Ствол шахты «Скипо-Клетевая»
    в составе проектной документации ОАО «Учалинский ГОК» Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник. Отработка запасов месторождения на полное развитие - 4,5 млн. т/год». В ходе расчета осуществлена проверка несущей способности крепи и оптимизация параметров армирования
    на участках пород, отнесенных к IV категории устойчивости.
  </p>
  <a class="jobs_more">Подробнее <span><ion-icon name="chevron-down-outline"></ion-icon></span></a>

</div>
```

Comment: Не надо создавать дубли - от этого ваш вопрос не станет понятней.

Comment: Мой код JS работает так что если я нажимаю на кнопку "Подробнее" у меня открываются сразу у всех item'ов открываются описание ,а нужно только у одного, на тот который я нажал

Answer (score 4):

```js
let moreValid;

function moreJobs() {
  $('.jobs_descript_full').hide();
  moreValid = false;

  $('.jobs_more').on('click', function() {
    $(this).siblings('.jobs_descript_full').toggle();
  });
}

moreJobs()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="job_item">

  <p class="jobs_title">Корректировка проекта полигона твердых отходов ПАО «Распадская»</p>
  <p class="jobs_descript">Сбор и анализ исходных данных, обоснование технических и технологических решений по объекту «Корректировка проекта полигона твердых отходов ПАО «Распадская».</p>
  <p class="jobs_descript_full">В рамках реализации специальных технических условий (СТУ) на проектирование объекта АО «Учалинский ГОК». Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник. Ствол шахты «Скипо-Клетевая» в составе проектной документации АО «Учалинский ГОК». Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник.
    Отработка запасов месторождения на полное развитие - 4,5 млн. т/год выполнен Отчет от 22 июля 2021 г. о НИР «Расчет крепи и корректировка параметров армирования крепи по объекту АО «Учалинский ГОК». Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник. Ствол шахты «Скипо-Клетевая»
    в составе проектной документации ОАО «Учалинский ГОК» Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник. Отработка запасов месторождения на полное развитие - 4,5 млн. т/год». В ходе расчета осуществлена проверка несущей способности крепи и оптимизация параметров армирования
    на участках пород, отнесенных к IV категории устойчивости.
  </p>
  <a class="jobs_more">Подробнее <span><ion-icon name="chevron-down-outline"></ion-icon></span></a>

</div>

<div class="job_item">

  <p class="jobs_title">Расчет крепи ствола шахты «Скипо-Клетевая» рудника месторождения «Юбилейное»</p>
  <p class="jobs_descript">Научно-исследовательская работа (НИР) от 28 июля 2021 г. «Расчет крепи ствола шахты «Скипо-Клетевой» ООО «Башкирская медь» месторождение «Юбилейное» и сопряжений ствола с горизонтами».</p>
  <p class="jobs_descript_full">В рамках реализации специальных технических условий (СТУ) на проектирование объекта АО «Учалинский ГОК». Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник. Ствол шахты «Скипо-Клетевая» в составе проектной документации АО «Учалинский ГОК». Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник.
    Отработка запасов месторождения на полное развитие - 4,5 млн. т/год выполнен Отчет от 22 июля 2021 г. о НИР «Расчет крепи и корректировка параметров армирования крепи по объекту АО «Учалинский ГОК». Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник. Ствол шахты «Скипо-Клетевая»
    в составе проектной документации ОАО «Учалинский ГОК» Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник. Отработка запасов месторождения на полное развитие - 4,5 млн. т/год». В ходе расчета осуществлена проверка несущей способности крепи и оптимизация параметров армирования
    на участках пород, отнесенных к IV категории устойчивости.
  </p>
  <a class="jobs_more">Подробнее <span><ion-icon name="chevron-down-outline"></ion-icon></span></a>

</div>

<div class="job_item">

  <p class="jobs_title">Расчет крепи ствола шахты «Скипо-Клетевая» Ново-Учалинского подземного рудника</p>
  <p class="jobs_descript">Научно-исследовательская работа (НИР) от 22 июля 2021 г. «Расчет крепи и корректировка параметров армирования крепи по объекту «АО «Учалинский ГОК». Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник. Ствол шахты «Скипо-Клетевая» в составе проектной документации «ОАО
    «Учалинский ГОК» Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник. Отработка запасов месторождения на полное развитие - 4,5 млн. т/год».</p>
  <p class="jobs_descript_full">В рамках реализации специальных технических условий (СТУ) на проектирование объекта АО «Учалинский ГОК». Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник. Ствол шахты «Скипо-Клетевая» в составе проектной документации АО «Учалинский ГОК». Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник.
    Отработка запасов месторождения на полное развитие - 4,5 млн. т/год выполнен Отчет от 22 июля 2021 г. о НИР «Расчет крепи и корректировка параметров армирования крепи по объекту АО «Учалинский ГОК». Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник. Ствол шахты «Скипо-Клетевая»
    в составе проектной документации ОАО «Учалинский ГОК» Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник. Отработка запасов месторождения на полное развитие - 4,5 млн. т/год». В ходе расчета осуществлена проверка несущей способности крепи и оптимизация параметров армирования
    на участках пород, отнесенных к IV категории устойчивости.
  </p>
  <a class="jobs_more">Подробнее <span><ion-icon name="chevron-down-outline"></ion-icon></span></a>

</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо.